# What's the key for sorting album with date of addition in iOS developer?

Tags: ios, sorting, phasset, phphotolibrary

If sorting album with date of creation, I could give the key `creationDate`, so what's the key for date added? `additionDate`? No, it's incorrect.

```swift
NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)
```

Comment: All of the information can be easily found in apple's documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phfetchoptions?language=objc#1965657 . See the chart with all the supported keys.

Comment: @JonRose Thank you, but there is no this key, so is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the publicly available methods/keys here [PHFetchOptions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phfetchoptions?language=objc#1965657)

If what you’re looking for is not listed then it means that there is either no way to do it OR it is considered a private API in most cases.

Comment: Thank you, and is there any way that sorting with adding date?

Comment: @leo based on the link I sent, no.